# Components of double covariant derivative.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, connections

My question is simple: Could you please explain (unfortunately, it means perform an step-by-step calculation) why the components of double covariant is given by $(1)$?

> $$ (\nabla_{u}\nabla_{v}w)^{a} = u^{c}v^{b}\nabla_{c}\nabla_{b}w^{a}+(u^{c}\nabla_{c}v^{b})\nabla_{b}w^{a} \tag{1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a direct computation using the Leibniz rule: $$\nabla_u\nabla_vw = u^b\nabla_b(v^c\nabla_cw) \stackrel{(\ast)}{=} u^bv^c\nabla_b\nabla_cw + (u^b\nabla_b v^c)\nabla_cw.$$

Comment: So, is it correct to write the vector field as:

$$\nabla_{u}\nabla_{v} w = [u^{b}v^{c}\nabla_{b}\nabla_{c}w^{a}+(u^{b}\nabla_{b}v^{c})\nabla_{c}w^{a}]\partial_{a} $$

?

Comment: Yes, by definition.